# Angular routing script fetching and route in browser tied together unlike angulajs webpack can use publicpath

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that we are bringing angular into.  We are using the angular-cli to build the front end.  We started off with AngularJS and got everything working but decided to upgrade it to angular 6. We have everything working except for lazy loading routing.  The problem is the route in the browser is tied to the route used to fetch static resources such as lazy loaded modules (which are not packed into main.js).  We configured HashLocationStrategy because the routing in our mvc application is just too complicated to solve that server side with any of the solutions described out there (they all use a catch all "{*url}" route on the server side).

My scenario is this.  The portion of the application that is angular is browsed to using an MVC route like this: "http://example.com/AngularApp/Myapp/Index" or something equivalent.  However, this application is a dynamic portion of the overall app and is deployed into the AREAS folder of the MVC application.  So when I click on a lazy loaded module it attempts to get the js file from "http://example.com/AngularApp/MyApp/Index/lazymodule.js".  It does this because of the base tag.  The actual file is at "http://example.com/areas/angularapp/scripts/lazymodule.js".

If I change the base tag url to the areas folder it screws up all the routes in the browser URL and I start getting urls that look like "http://example.com/areas/angularapp/mymodule", which breaks all sorts of things with the regular MVC application code.

I don't want these two things linked. In AngularJS I solved this problem using the publicPath setting in webpack and everything worked fine.

Is there a way I can configure angular to fetch resources from one path but allow the app URLS to stay relative to how the application was invoked?